# Can i throw an exception from custom filter to force Spring Cloud Gateway to return 401?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I have the following filter that examines a certain header in the request:

```
class AuthHeadersFilter(
    private val objectMapper: ObjectMapper
) : AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<AuthHeadersFilter.Config>() {
    override fun apply(config: Config?): GatewayFilter? {
        return GatewayFilter { exchange, chain ->

            val request = exchange.request.mutate()
                .headers { httpHeaders ->
                    httpHeaders.remove(AUTHORIZATION)
                    val jwtClaims = httpHeaders[AUTHORIZATION]
                        ?.firstOrNull()
                        ?.let {
                            jwtClaims(it)
                        } ?: throw IllegalStateException("authorisation header is missing")

                    val permissions: List<Permissions> = jwtClaims
                        .getStringClaimValue("authz")
                        ?.let {
                            objectMapper.readValue(it)
                        } ?: throw IllegalStateException("Authz claim is missing")

                    permissions.forEach {
                        httpHeaders.add("X-OrgId", it.scope.org)
                    }
                }.build()
            chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(request).build())
        }
    }
```

As you can see i throw IllegalState Exception when the needed header is missing or the authz claim is missing in the token. This in turn makes the spring gateway return status code 500. How can i change this to force Spring Gateway return 401 or 403?

Answer (score 0):

Doing this might will help you.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("{ ");
sb.append("\"error\": \"Unauthorized\" ");
sb.append("\"message\": \"Unauthorized\"");<--- your message here
sb.append("\"path\": \"")
  .append(request.getRequestURL())
  .append("\"");
sb.append("} ");

response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);  
response.getWriter().write(sb.toString());
return;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).